# Remove (both) equal entries from DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview, defaultview

I want to remove equal entries from DataTable.
I tried `DefaultView`, but it only removes the equals and not all entries which including them.

```
DataView view = table1.DefaultView;
DataTable tbl = view.ToTable();
return tbl;
```

Comment: Give an example of what end result should be with source DataTable.

Comment: What is criteria for entities to be equal?

Comment: there are no criteria for entities, tbl contains two tables with some equal rows, and I only want to return the different rows...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicate(DataTable dataTable, string columname)
{
  Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();
  List<String> duplicates = new List<String>();
 foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
 {
   if (hashTable .Contains(datarow [columname]))
   {
    duplicateList.Add(datarow );
   }
   else
   {
    hashTable .Add(datarow [columname], string.Empty); 
   }
 }
  //Now remove the duplicates .
  foreach (DataRow datarow in duplicates )
  dataTable.Rows.Remove(datarow );
  return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: tbl contains two tables with some equal rows, and I only want to return the different rows...